# Not able to send mail, when i tried to sent from yii

Tags: yii

In my sitecontroller.php

I have this method:

```
public function actionContact()
```

This has to send a mail to adminmail.

```
mail(Yii::app()->params['adminEmail'],$subject,$model->body,$headers)
```

But, when i submit the views/contact.php form it's not sending any mail to adminmail.

here,How can i send this mail from contact.php to my adminmail?

here is my models/ContactForm.php:

http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=ccty32Nu

here is my Controllers/SiteController.php:

http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=sWWQpegR

Comment: paste the full code for your contact action and the contents of your contact.php file, that would help us troubleshoot!

Comment: Is server mail system configured?

Comment: from where are u sending the email?localhost??

Comment: yes, from localhost only